# How to set an arraylist of images to 6 imageviews

Tags: java, android, arraylist, imageview, bundle

I have an arraylist of images in bundle, and in next fragment i have 6 imageView and i want to get the images and set them to imageViews. How can i do this?

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            ArrayList<Integer> list=new ArrayList<>();
            //StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCheck().size(); i++) {
                Item_obj items = it.get(i);
                if (items.isSelected) {
                    list.add(items.image);
                }
            }
            bundle.putIntegerArrayList("IMAGE", list);
            info.setArguments(bundle);

            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, info).commit();
```

Now i'm getting the images in next fragment.

```
public static final String TEXT = "TEXT";

TextView dots;
EditText skills_description;
Button clear, save, languages;

CircleImageView circleImageView1, circleImageView2, circleImageView3,
        circleImageView4, circleImageView5, circleImageView6;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mainView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.personal_info, container, false);
    init(mainView);

    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    if (bundle != null) {
        ArrayList<Integer> s = bundle.getIntegerArrayList("IMAGE");
        if (s != null) {



        }
    }
    return mainView;
}
```

You see i have 6 circleImageViews and i want to set the images of arraylist to this 6 circleImageViews. How to do this?

Adapter class

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Context ct;
LayoutInflater lInflater;
ArrayList<Item_obj> objects;
PersonalInfoFragment info = new PersonalInfoFragment();

MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Item_obj> itemObj) {
    ct = context;
    objects = itemObj;
    lInflater = (LayoutInflater) ct
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return objects.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return objects.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
        view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_items, parent, false);
    }

    Item_obj io = getItem_obj(position);
    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.select_lang)).setText(io.language);
    ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView)).setImageResource(io.image);

    CheckBox cb = view.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
    cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(myCheckChangeList);
    cb.setTag(position);
    cb.setChecked(io.isSelected);

    return view;
}

Item_obj getItem_obj(int position) {
    return (Item_obj) getItem(position);
}

ArrayList<Item_obj> getCheck() {
    ArrayList<Item_obj> item = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Item_obj i : objects) {
        if (i.isSelected) {
            if (item.size() > 5) {
                Toast.makeText(ct, "Can't select more than 6 languages", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                i.isSelected=false;
                break;
            } else {
                item.add(i);
            }
        }
    }
    return item;
}}
```

Comment: ArrayList<Integer> list=new ArrayList<>();` That looks more like an array list of integers.

Comment: What you mean? .

Comment: I know english bad, if i said something wrong i'm sorry.

Comment: `items.image` is an integer, right?

Comment: yes of course, i have listView with checkboxes, and which image the user checks from list view i'm adding that to arrayList and then i adding the arrayList to bundle. Then getting the arrayList in next fragment i want to get the checked images and set them to this circleImageViews.

Comment: how is that integer related to image?

Comment: Image type is integer.

Comment: is that image id or something? if you are adding integer to that arraylist, you can get only that integer in next fragment.

Comment: That's an id. .

Comment: can you somehow get image with that id?

Comment: Man that's a custom adapter i'm getting the image from listView

Comment: can you show more code? may be adapter? and populating `it` list

Comment: Check the code.

Comment: `Item_obj items = it.get(i);` how do you populate `it`? `items.image` what kind of id is that? resource id? Are you fetching image from server?

Comment: No that's a resource id

Comment: like `R.drawable.imageID` that kind of id?

Comment: yes of course...

Comment: `CircleImageView ` is library? https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView

Comment: Yes, but there's no any difference between normal imageView.

Comment: is that the same exact library that i mentioned?

Comment: Yes of course ..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164764/discussion-between-hayk-mkrtchyan-and-aswin-p-ashok).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this.

```
Bundle bundle = getArguments();
if (bundle != null) {
    ArrayList<Integer> s = bundle.getIntegerArrayList("IMAGE");
    if (s != null) {
        for(int i=0;i<s.size();i++){
             switch(i){
                 case 0 : circleImageView1.setImageResource(s.get(i));
                          break; 
                 case 1 : circleImageView2.setImageResource(s.get(i));
                          break;
                 case 2 : circleImageView3.setImageResource(s.get(i));
                          break;
                 case 3 : circleImageView4.setImageResource(s.get(i));
                          break;
                 case 4 : circleImageView5.setImageResource(s.get(i));
                          break;
                 case 5 : circleImageView6.setImageResource(s.get(i));
                          break;
                 default: break;
             }
        }
    }
}
```